# How to configure proxy to acess SSO configured environment from localhost in protractor?

Tags: protractor

At first, my application was not SSO configured so I was able to run the application on my localhost server in protractor by the concept of creating proxy files.
But I cannot able to run my protractor scripts after the environment is configured to SSO. Do I need to any other setup to make my scripts work on localhost for SSO configured applications.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Also what problem do you have (any specific errors etc)